# Always create unique keys whenever possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

Should you always create unique keys whenever possible?

For example let's say I have a table with three fields, student ID, first name, last name and the student ID is the primary key.

If no two students have the first & last name, should I create a unique key for those two fields?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use composite keys? Or always use surrogate keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029485/use-composite-keys-or-always-use-surrogate-keys)

Comment: Your StudentID, a primary key, is already a unique key... why would you need anything else?

Comment: Will there ever be a possibility of adding more students? Then you may get duplicate names.

Comment: Primary keys are, by definition, always unique. You're really asking about **surrogate** keys.

Comment: @Paul: If another combination of columns is always unique then that should also be enforced.

Comment: No student ID is unique/primary.  adding a unique key prevents you from EVER having two students with the same first/last names.  So if you do get 2 John Smith's next year... what then?  Don't enforce uniqueness unless you WANT it to be unique, not because it doesn't exist this year.

Comment: @xQbert I think you're the only other poster here who understands that he's asking if first&last should be UNIQUE, and not the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Rows are uniquely identified by the primary key, the whole key and nothing but the key, so help me Codd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use unique indexes even when you already have a primary key when the column or combination of columns are unique. It's good to have constraints in your database to prevent bad data. However, this is not what you have in your case. Even if you currently have no students with duplicate names that can easily happen in the future. Names are not unique in the world.

U.S. Social Security numbers are almost always unique (they can be reused after a number of years, but it's unlikely to ever happen in your case), so they might make for a good candidate for a unique index. If you have non-U.S. students though then you would need to make the column nullable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, usually having unique IDs (surrogate keys) is best.  In this case, last name and first name are not enough for a primary key.  Even if you no duplicate names now, you can't be sure you won't have two John Smith's in the future.

Comment: He's not talking about having an ID, he means a unique key constraint on first & last. Which with your statement of "can't be sure you won't have two John Smith's" implies he SHOULDN'T denote them as unique.

Comment: @Jean-Bernard Pellerin - thanks for the clarification, may answer does not fully address that as yours does.  The correct idea is to model your table after the underlying model, and there is no real world rule that people can't have the same first and last name.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make the assumption that no two students will have the same name.

When the underlying model suggests it, it is a good idea to create unique keys. Constraints like these will ensure cohesive data and prevent errors. But in your case the underlying model does not suggest this to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Unique keys should follow business definitions; if the studentID is a "semi-natural" key (it has unique meaning that exists beyond your specific database), then that should suffice as your unique key.

If the studentID is simply an identity value that is assigned by the database as a row-number, then you probably need some other unique key to avoid entering the same student twice.

Comment: Agreed except first, last and middle are not good enough to have uniqueness, thus unfit for a unique key.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive primary key with no relation to data domain is one of widely accepted best practices
( just imagine - one of your students decides to marry )

Another good practice (though from NoSql) world is to use GUID - this way keys are unique,  and different datasets can be mixed in same table without collisions.

PS: you could save some storage space,  but today it is cheap and there is no need to sacrifice good practices for it

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

If you ever need to update or delete rows from the table, it is very advantageous to have something to uniquely identify each row in the table.

With your example, I don't think it's possible to guarantee no two students will share the same name.  Even adding a date of birth still can't guarantee they'll always be unique. I'd recommend adding an auto incrementing INT or BIGINT as the primary key.

You can always add the Unique constraint as well and remove it if it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do it is use an auto-generated Guid (Globally Unique Identifier) to identify a student.  It is "guarenteed" to be unique every time it is generated.  Names can change (like when somebody gets married), but some auto generated value has no meaning so should never need to be changed.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: Not all platforms or RDBMS products support generating and/or storing these. They can also be super expensive to use in `JOIN` statements.

Comment: That doesn't inherently make a good primary key, unless you rethink your clustered index.

Answer (score 0):

Your database constraints should be DBMS understood business rules.  Is there a business rule that states that no two students may have the same first and last name combination? I presume not, therefore do not create a unique key for those two fields. Perhaps best not to presume, though, and ask a business domain expert e.g. the enrolment officer.

Note that a row in this table is a proposition I.e. that there exists a student enrolled with first name 'x' and last name 'y' and student ID 'z'. Clearly the DBMS has not concept of whether this proposition is true in the real world. What normally happens is that there will be a trusted source to verify data. The enterprise will authorize an officer (director etc) in this role. Let's say it is the enrolment officer who is responsible for verifying that 'x y' is a real person, that they are eligible to be enrolled, and the person is who they say they are. Typically, they will require sight of documents (certificates, passport, etc), take up references, interview the person, check public records, etc. Of course, the enrolment officer may delegate their responsibility to other members of staff or engage an agent.

At some point they will be satisfied and for convenience will issue they own identifier, the student ID. Mistakes do happen and it may turn out that this value is not unique, in which case it would be the enrolment officer's responsibility to resolve the problem and issue a new student to. Perhaps they will use software to generate the value to mitigate against such problems. The student ID will be issued to the student and will be used within the enterprise to identify the person for the convenience of all concerned. They may even be issued with a document (e.g. photo ID card) to assist in identification, based on the level of trust in a given context (e.g. may need to produce photo ID to sit an exam). If the student forgets their ID, loses their issued documents, etc then the enrolment office will be able to retrieve it from records e.g. with reference to copy documents taken during the verification process; they are unlikely to use first name and last name alone.

The point is, the trusted source for the identifier is the enrolment officer on behalf of the enterprise, rather than the database, the DBMS or any other kind of software involved in the process. Therefore, it probably is acceptable to make student ID the sole identifier for stents within the database. Consider, however, that an auto-increment column generated on one hardware build of a single DBMS within the enterprise is probably not suitable for the allocation of such significant identifier values.